# When would I use the "Mark directory as ..." option in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am a newcomer finding my way around the IntelliJ IDE, for which I am currently using for coding in Scala.

Right clicking in the Project window brings up a pop-up, with "Mark Directory As ..." as an option, with the following choices:

- Sources Root
- Test Sources Root
- Resources Root
- Test Resources Root
- Excluded
- Generated Sources Root

Can I know would I use the "Mark Directory As ..." option? And also what would each of the choices do? I have tried looking around, but so far most websites have been rather vague with their explanations.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: WebStorm actually [documents marking folders as Test/Excluded/Resources](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/configuring-project-structure.html#a75e2b93), though it's unclear [what that actually *does*](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-38749).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Lets go through the options:

- **Sources Root** - this is where your actual project code goes - typically in `src/main/scala` (though you can change that, or add extra source directories in your build). Directories nested below this level should be packages. Intellij needs to know these are sources so it can highlight them, check them for errors, etc.
- **Test Sources Root** - likewise, this is where your test sources live, and will often mirror the package structure of your `main` sources.
- **Resources Root** - where non-compiled files (such as i18n messages or configuration) live, which need to be deployed with the final artifact (jar or war or whatever).
- **Test Resources Root** - non-compiled files used by tests, such as `.sql` fixtures, etc.
- **Excluded** - anything you don't want Intellij to index or care about at all. If you have a directory tree (e.g. a database) in your project root which isn't part of your code base you should mark it as **Excluded**, since this will prevent Intellij indexing the files. Not only can indexing take a long time on large projects, having a lot of non-project files indexed by the IDE will slow down the frequently-used *Go to Class/File/Symbol* operations, and cause them to offer irrelevant suggestions.
- **Generated Sources Root** - sources that are managed by a build tool or some other process. For example, the Play Framework (2.x) generates Scala code from HTML and routing info automatically when the project is built. It's important that generated sources are marked as such (as opposed to normal code, or non-code) so that the IDE can resolve references to it (ensuring code validity) whilst being aware that you shouldn't edit it yourself. This will also prevent generated code being offered as suggestions in the *Go to Class/File/Symbol* dialogs.

If you're using SBT you might not have to use "Mark directory as..." manually much at all, since the Intellij SBT plugin has grown smarter about inferring source, resources, and generated source directories automatically from the `build.sbt` file.

It's worth noting that Intellij plugins can add additional options to the "Mark directory as..." menu - for example, the Python plugin has a "Template Folder" option.

Comment: Is "Sources Root" only required for Java code, or also for other programming languages?