# IntelliJ IDEA says "unresolved reference" on everything (Python, virtual environment)

Tags: python, intellij-idea

How can I get IntelliJ IDEA to recognize common Python modules? IntelliJ IDEA is complaining "unresolved reference" on everything despite that I have added my virtual environment as a "Python interpreter" and invalidated caches. These [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20877106/using-intellijidea-within-an-existing-virtualenv)[(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102908/how-do-i-get-intellij-to-recognize-common-python-modules) related questions did not help resolve the issue.

[image: unresolved reference]
[image: Interpreter is setup]

Comment: check whether it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236824/unresolved-reference-issue-in-pycharm

Comment: I marked my root folder as "sources", but I couldn't find any place where I could check a box that says "add source roots to pythonpath".

Comment: Have you tried to run "File | Invallidate Caches"?

Comment: Yes. (this text exists to fill minimum comment length)

Comment: @AtteJuvonen , Could you fix the issue? I've been trying to fix it for a couple of days.

Comment: No, I moved from IDEA to PyCharm because of this. Good luck!

Comment: @AtteJuvonen , today a new version of IntelliJ and Python plugin were released and they fixed the issue to me. Just give a try

Comment: @y.bedrov I did and it worked for a while but at some point the problem reappeared

Answer (score 8):

The errors are caused by wrong source roots configuration. Your project doesn't know where to locate the reference.

> Add a new content root From the main menu, select File | Project
> Structure⌘; and click Project Settings | Modules.
>
> Select the necessary module and then open the Sources tab in the
> right-hand part of the dialog.
>
> Click Add Content Root and specify the folder that you want to add as
> a new content root.

The link is [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/content-roots.html#adding_content_root).

IntelliJ support discussed the same issue at [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203465584-Import-unresolved-references).

Another stack overflow discussion is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39254216/when-would-i-use-the-mark-directory-as-option-in-intellij-idea/39255116).

Answer (score 2):

you can try this :

*Project Structure -> SDKs -> "+" -> Python SDK*

*Project -> Project SDK -> Python 2.7.10* #Choose the python version that you want

Comment: I still have the same issue.

Comment: which Python version are you using and on which OS

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 19.04, Python 3.8 and python 3.7

Comment: Solved it for me, seems like a restart of the IDE was necessary before the changes took effect.

Answer (score 1):

This fixed for me when I setup the Python interpreter again. Apparently the problem was that the Python SDK's classpath was empty.